# Can we use a derived type while overriding a method without using method hiding

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Don't want to use method hiding here as its a kind of a work-around. Any other suggestion or idea?

```
public abstract class Product 
{
    public abstract ProductData Data { get ; protected set ;}
}

public class SpecificProduct : Product
{
    public override SpecificProductData Data {get; } 

}

public class ProductData
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class SpecificProductData : ProductData
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider using generics.

Comment: This base class need to hold more properties where similar behavior is expected . That will cause multiple Generic types to get passed as a parameter :(

Comment: Your code seems to violate [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).